# Remove multi line comments in vim

Tags: vim

I want to remove a multi line comment in vim:

```
/**
 * Factory for creating [MainViewModel]
 *
 * @param arg the repository to pass to [MainViewModel]
 */
```

I tried

```
%s,/\*.*\*/,,gc
```

but it doesn't work for multiple lines and

```
s,/\*\_.*\*/,,gc
```

removes whole content between First comment's beginning and last comment's ending.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works:

```
%s,/\*\_.{-}\*/,,g
```

`\_` includes newlines in the following character set.

`{-}` instead of `*` tells vim to be non-greedy in matching.

Comment: `:%s,/\*\_.\{-}\*/\n,,g` if  using nvim, in my case I wanted to delete the newline at the end too